# Do LLVM IR global variable and function declaration must use `external` and `extern_weak` linkage type?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

In [LLVM IR linkage type](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#linkage-types), it says `All Global Variables and Functions have one of the following types of linkage:` at first, then list several linkage types such as `private`, `internal`, `common`, `appending` etc.

At the bottom of this section, it then says `It is illegal for a global variable or function declaration to have any linkage type other than external or extern_weak.`.

I'm confused by this document, since I don't understand why other linkage types (such as `private` `internal`, `common`, `appending`) is forbidden.

Answer (score 3):

A declaration declares that another linkage unit (.o file) will define the thing being declared. Therefore, the declaration and definition must both have such a linkage type that they are the same thing.

The forbidden linkage types are ones that don't make sense or cannot work, for one reason or another. `private`, for example — if something is named in two different linkage units, how can the thing named be private? To which unit is it private? And so on.